# Can a button be used to add another Label to the screen in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want the last button in the pop up to add a label to the previous screen with the text of whatever in entered into the text input in the pop up but I cant find a way to do so, is it possible?

I want the button with id add to add a label to screen the List every time it is clicked, and the text of said label should be whatever value put into text inputs with the ids lab, club, and blub

And if it is possible, how can I do it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Python :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import time
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Enter_Name(Screen):
    input_1 = StringProperty()
    def line(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('list').lab_text = self.airline.text    
    pass

class Pop(Screen):
    air_craft = StringProperty()
    def lad(self):
        plane = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('pop').lab_text = self.airplane.text
        self.plane = plane
    
    
    
class List(Screen):
    Enter_Name.line
    def add(self):
        show_popup()

def show_popup():
    show = Pop()

    pop_up_window = Popup(title="Add Route", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop_up_window.open()



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("pot.kv")

class am4(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv



if __name__ == "__main__":
    am4().run()
```

Kivy :

```
#:kivy 1.0


WindowManager:
    Enter_Name
    List
    Pop
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
#LOGIN
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
<Enter_Name>
    airline: input_1
    name: 'enter_name'
    id: enter_nom
    FloatLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: root.size
        Label:
            text: "Name of Airline?"
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":1}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'input_one'
            id: input_1
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.20, "top":0.6}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top":0.4}
            text: "Enter"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = 'list'
                root.line()
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
#MAIN
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
<List>
    lab_text: ''
    name: 'list'
    FloatLayout:
        
        Label:
            text: root.lab_text
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.38, "top":1.1}
            font_size: 50

        Label:
            text: '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.38, "top":1}
            font_size: 50

        Button:
            text: "Add Route"
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.79, "top":0.99}
            on_release: root.add()


<Pop>
    name: "pop"
    airplane: air_craft
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: "Aircraft"
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.38, "top":1.45}
        Label:
            id: club
            text: "Departure"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":1.45}
        Label:
            id: blub
            text: "Arrival"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":1.45}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'aircraft'
            id: air_craft
            size_hint: 0.23, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":0.9}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'departure'
            id: leaving
            size_hint: 0.23, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":0.9}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'arrival'
            id: arriving
            size_hint: 0.23, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.76, "top":0.9}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top":0.5}
            id: add
            text: "Add"
            on_release:
                root.lad()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that does what I think you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class Enter_Name(Screen):
    input_1 = StringProperty()

    def line(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('list').lab_text = self.airline.text

class ListRow(BoxLayout):
    ac = StringProperty('')
    arr = StringProperty('')
    lv = StringProperty('')


class Pop(RelativeLayout):
    def lad(self, ac, arr, lv):
        list_scr = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('list')
        if ac != '' or arr != '' or lv != '':
            box_layout = list_scr.ids.box_layout
            box_layout.add_widget(ListRow(ac=ac, arr=arr, lv=lv))
        list_scr.pop.dismiss()


class List(Screen):
    Enter_Name.line
    pop = ObjectProperty(None)

    def add(self):
        self.pop = show_popup()


def show_popup():
    show = Pop()

    pop_up_window = Popup(title="Add Route", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop_up_window.open()
    return pop_up_window


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


# kv = Builder.load_file("pot.kv")
kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.0


WindowManager:
    Enter_Name
    List
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
#LOGIN
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
<Enter_Name>
    airline: input_1
    name: 'enter_name'
    id: enter_nom
    FloatLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: root.size
        Label:
            text: "Name of Airline?"
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":1}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'input_one'
            id: input_1
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.20, "top":0.6}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top":0.4}
            text: "Enter"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = 'list'
                root.line()
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
#MAIN
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
<List>
    lab_text: ''
    name: 'list'
    BoxLayout:
        id: box_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: 50
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
            
                Label:
                    id: lab1
                    text: root.lab_text
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    #pos_hint: {"x": -0.38, "top":1}
                    font_size: 50
        
                Button:
                    text: "Add Route"
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    #pos_hint: {"x":0.79, "top":1}
                    on_release: root.add()
    
            Label:
                text: '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
                size_hint: 1, 0.3
                #pos_hint: {"x": -0.38, "top":0.99}
                font_size: 50
<ListRow>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: (1, None)
    height: self.minimum_height
    Label:
        text: 'Aircraft: ' + root.ac
        halign: 'left'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
    Label:
        text: 'Leave: ' + root.lv
        halign: 'left'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
    Label:
        text: 'Arrive: ' + root.arr
        halign: 'left'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]


<Pop>
    airplane: air_craft
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: "Aircraft"
            pos_hint: {"x": -0.38, "top":1.45}
        Label:
            id: club
            text: "Departure"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":1.45}
        Label:
            id: blub
            text: "Arrival"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":1.45}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'aircraft'
            id: air_craft
            size_hint: 0.23, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":0.9}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'departure'
            id: leaving
            size_hint: 0.23, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":0.9}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            name: 'arrival'
            id: arriving
            size_hint: 0.23, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.76, "top":0.9}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top":0.5}
            id: add
            text: "Add"
            on_release:
                root.lad(air_craft.text, arriving.text, leaving.text)
''')


class am4(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    am4().run()
```

Some of the significant changes that I made:

- Redefined the `Pop` class as extending `RelativeLayout` instead of `Screen` and removed `Pop` from the children of `WindowManager`.
- Defined a `ListRow` class that is added to the `List` `Screen` when the `lad()` method is called.
- Added arguments to the `lad()` method for information to be added, and added a `dismiss()` call to close the `Popup`.
- The `show_pop()` method now returns the created `Popup` instance which is saved in the `List` `Screen` for use of `dismiss()`.
- Redesigned the `List` `Screen` using a vertical `BoxLayout` to make adding `ListRows` simpler.

The `kv` is loaded using `Builder.load_string()` in the above code, but that is only for my own convenience.